# How to show that $\|f\|=|f(a)|+|f(b)|$ does not defines a norm on $C[a,b]$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

How to show that $\|f\|=|f(a)|+|f(b)|$ does not defines a norm on $C[a,b]$?

I can't find a continuous function where I can have $f(a)=f(b)=0$ but $f\neq 0$. Can you help me with that if there is such a function.

Comment: $f(x)=(x-a)\cdot(x-b)$

Comment: Yes this will work. So I just have to think of a polynomial which have a and b as roots. It didn't came in to my mind thank you.